# bash one liner to combine text files line by line except for the first line in every file except for the first file

Tags: bash, unix, text, text-processing

I am currently doing it using this script:

```
head -1 file001.txt > all.txt; tail -n +2 -q *.txt >> all.txt
```

it is doing alright, gettting the header from first file and then concatenating the others.

### Problem is:

the other lines are all in one line, rather than each being in separate line. Please help to correct this problem.

if you have any other one liner that does the job, perfect, it is welcome.

### the desired answer will be:

get the header from **any** of the files with that extension, I don't want to give any specific file name like **file001.txt**, i'd prefer it to take it from any file, because anyway they have the same headers. But it is possible that my file names don't be the pattern **file001.txt**, that is why I say any file with that extension.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `the other lines are all in one line, rather than each being in separate line` ?

Comment: in the output file,i have two lines! one is the header and the rest of the lines are all concatenated in the same line, rather than each line which is coming from separate file being in separate line on the output file.

Comment: You need to show an example of how the lines are concatenated and how they should be separated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing newlines at the end of your textfiles, `tail` doesn't add them on it's own. Most likely adding newlines to the end of the files is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1&&!ctr++;FNR!=1' *.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `FNR` is the line number of the current input file
2. `ctr` is a variable that starts at 0 and is incremented
    every time we see the first line of a file
3. `ctr` is only zero for the first input file, so `!ctr` is only true
    for the first file.
4. Without an explicit action, the current input line is printed.
5. The first condition prints line 1 of each file if `ctr` is false.
6. The second condition prints a line if it is not the first line of a file.

Demonstration:

```
$ printf '%s\n' hdr f1 f2 > f1.txt
$ printf '%s\n' hdr g1 g2 > f2.txt
$ printf '%s\n' hdr h1 h2 > f3.txt
$ awk 'FNR==1&&!ctr++;FNR!=1' *.txt
hdr
f1
f2
g1
g2
h1
h2
```

A slightly simpler command:

```
awk '!ctr++ || FNR!=1' *.txt
```

which prints a line if either `ctr` is zero (which is only true for the first line of the first file) or the line is not the first line of a file.

Answer (score 0):

try this and it might work for you:

```
sed -e '2,${/^YOUR_HEADER/d' -e '}' *.txt > all.txt
```

Comment: This just looks like a lucky guess without any useful explanation as to what it does.